# subclass uitableview already in a UIView

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, uitableview

I am trying to implement Leah's "Pull to Refresh" code (https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh) in to my UITableView. However, I have a UIView, so cannot subclass the tableViewController as is required by this.

My structure is

```
UIView
  - UITableView
```

So there's a UITableView inside my main UIView. I use a UIViewController obviously - and this cannot really change (I think!)

I have tried to change the class in interface builder to the custom uitableviewcontroller above (the pull to refresh one) but it doesn't let me.

Any ideas on how I can subclass the UITableView - NOT the tableViewController??

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:

Change PullToRefreshTableViewController so that it subclasses UIViewController, NOT UITableViewController. Next, add a UITableView * property called tableView to PullToRefreshTableViewController and synthesize it. Lastly, modify your view controller so that it subclasses PullToRefreshTableViewController instead of UIViewController.

That should give you a working implementation of it.